# How to use Word Object when Protected View is on?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have some code in VB.net that cycles through a directory of documents (.docx) and updates them.

The code is fine other than if there is one document in there that is considered as 'Originated from the Internet' then the code stops since Word will by default open it in Protected View (visibility is set to false deliberately).

Now, I know how to change the trust center settings, but I need my application to run on anyones machine  and the users (my clientele) are not likely to know how to do it.

Is there a way round this?

Thanks.

---EDIT---

In a recent example, one of the files I tried to open with my code was added to the directory externally via an FTP (by me). so when my code was cycling through all the docs in the directory, the code halted at this file since it had now 'Originated form the internet'.

My issue is that once the document is opened, the code needs to continue and edit the document but my code cannot do so as it opened in 'Protected view'. As the word object is set to not be visible, this results in the code pausing for use input (Ordinarily choosing to Edit the document) but they can't see it to do so.

Manually changing the Trust center settings is unfortunately not an option here, as this code is being run on hundreds of different machines by people who are not comfortable with changing it themselves - their perception is just that my code does not work,

Here's my code that cycle through a directory and inserts an image into the header of the document. It's sloppy I know but I'm quite new to this and learning every day. I've marked where the issue occurs with "'****THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS****"

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim oWrd As Word.Application
    Dim oTok As Word.InlineShape
    Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim GUID, PRTY As Scripting.Folder
    Dim fl As Scripting.File
    Dim sSure As MsgBoxResult
    Dim p, a, b, x, y, aa As Integer
    Dim bln As Boolean

    sSure = MsgBox("Are you Sure?", vbYesNo, "Really?")
    If sSure = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each GUID In FSO.GetFolder(TextBox1.Text).SubFolders
        For Each PRTY In FSO.GetFolder(GUID.Path).SubFolders
            For Each fl In FSO.GetFolder(PRTY.Path).Files
                a = a + 1
            Next
        Next
    Next
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Running..."
    oWrd = New Word.Application
    oWrd.ScreenUpdating = False
    oWrd.Visible = False
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0
    For Each GUID In FSO.GetFolder(TextBox1.Text).SubFolders
        For Each PRTY In FSO.GetFolder(GUID.Path).SubFolders
            For Each fl In FSO.GetFolder(PRTY.Path).Files
                x = x + 1
                If Not fl.Path Like "*\Land Registry\*" Then
                    If Not fl.Path Like "*\Billing\*" Then
                        If Not fl.Path Like "*\Attendance Notes\*" Then

                            If fl.Name Like "*(LH)*" Then

                                aa = aa + 1
                                GoTo c
                            End If
                            If FSO.FileExists(Split(fl.Path, ".")(0) & " (LH).dot") Then
                                aa = aa + 1
                                GoTo c
                            End If

                            y = y + 1
'****THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS****
                            oWrd.Documents.Open(fl.Path)
'If MS WORD DECIDES THIS DOCUMENT "ORIGINATED FROM THE INTERNET", THE CODE CANNOT RUN PAST THIS POINT DUE TO THE "PROTECTED VIEW" AND THE USER CAN'T SEE IT.
a:
                            Try
                                oWrd.Selection.Find.Text = "Dear "
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                p = p + 1
                                If p = 20 Then
                                    MsgBox("Too Many Rertys")
                                End If
                                GoTo a
                            End Try
                            bln = oWrd.Selection.Find.Execute
                            If bln = True Then

                                If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
                                    If oWrd.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False Then
b:
                                        Try
                                            oWrd.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
                                        Catch ex As Exception
                                            oWrd.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = True
                                            oWrd.Selection.HomeKey()

                                            oWrd.Selection.Find.Text = "^b"
                                            bln = oWrd.Selection.Find.Execute

                                            If bln = True Then
                                                oWrd.Selection.Delete()
                                                oWrd.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = False
                                            Else
                                                MsgBox("oops")
                                            End If
                                            GoTo b
                                        End Try
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    If oWrd.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True Then
                                        oWrd.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
                                    End If
                                End If
                                oWrd.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekFirstPageHeader


                                oWrd.Selection.WholeStory()
                                If oWrd.Selection.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
                                    Dim RSLT As VBA.MsgBoxResult

                                    RSLT = MsgBox("HEADER TOKEN DETECTED" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Would you like to continue?", vbYesNo, "WARNING")
                                    If RSLT = MsgBoxResult.No Then
                                        oWrd.Visible = True
                                        Exit Sub
                                    End If
                                End If

                                oTok = oWrd.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v353/catfinger/LetterheadToken_zps7f2a4851.png")
                                oTok.AlternativeText = "replace_Database.OtherTemplate_" & Split(ComboBox1.Text, " ")(0) & ".Content"

                                If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
                                    If Not TextBox2.Text = "" Then
                                        If CheckBox3.Checked = True Then
                                            oWrd.Selection.HomeKey()
                                        End If
                                        If CheckBox5.Checked = True Then
                                            oWrd.Selection.EndKey()
                                        End If
                                        For b = 1 To TextBox2.Text
                                            oWrd.Selection.TypeParagraph()
                                        Next
                                    End If
                                End If

                                oWrd.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument
                                If CheckBox8.Checked = True Then
                                    oWrd.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekFirstPageFooter


                                    Dim footPath As String = IO.Path.GetFullPath(My.Resources.ResourceManager.BaseName)
                                    footPath = footPath.Substring(0, footPath.Length - 39) & "Resources\LetterheadToken.png"
                                    oTok = oWrd.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(footPath)
                                    oTok.AlternativeText = "replace_Database.OtherTemplate_" & ComboBox2.Text & ".Content"

                                    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
                                        If Not TextBox3.Text = "" Then
                                            If CheckBox7.Checked = True Then
                                                oWrd.Selection.HomeKey()
                                            End If
                                            If CheckBox6.Checked = True Then
                                                oWrd.Selection.EndKey()
                                            End If
                                            For b = 1 To TextBox2.Text
                                                oWrd.Selection.TypeParagraph()
                                            Next
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                                If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
                                    oWrd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(Split(fl.Path, ".")(0) & " (LH).dot")
                                Else
                                    oWrd.ActiveDocument.Save()
                                End If
                            End If
                            oWrd.ActiveDocument.Close()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
c:
                ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = (x & " of " & a & " (" & y & " updates so far...) / (" & aa & " Skipped)")
                ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = (x / a * 100)
                Me.Refresh()
            Next
        Next
    Next

    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Finished..."
    MsgBox(y & " Letterheads were created out of a possible " & x & ".")
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this ended up being what I was looking for:

To force a doc into Protected View and edit it from there:

```
Sub OpenPVThenEdit

ProtectedViewWindows.Open("DOCUMENT PATH HERE")
ProtectedViewWindows(1).Edit

End Sub
```

------------OR-------------

If you have no other Word Documents open and want to do a check to see if the document has been opened in Protected View:

```
Sub TestForPVw

Documents.Open("DOCUMENT PATH HERE")
    If ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
            ProtectedViewWindows(1).Edit
    End If

End Sub
```

------------OR-------------

If you do have other Word Documents open and want to do a check to see if this specific document has been opened in Protected View (Untested):

```
Sub TestForPVw
Dim dDoc as Document
Set dDoc = Documents.Open("DOCUMENT PATH HERE")
    If ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
            ProtectedViewWindows(dDoc.Name).Edit
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be a few reasons why Word object is opened this way. Below are a few I list.

- A file skips or fails Office File Validation   Office File Validation is a security feature that scans files for file format exploits. If Office File Validation detects a possible exploit or some other unsafe file corruption, the file opens in Protected View.
- AES zone information determines that a file is not safe   Attachment Execution Services (AES) adds zone information to files that are downloaded by Outlook, Internet Explorer, and some other applications. If a file’s zone information indicates that the file originated from an untrusted website or the Internet, the downloaded file opens in Protected View.
- A user opens a file in Protected View   Users can open files in Protected View by choosing Open in Protected View in the Open dialog box, or by holding down the SHIFT key, choosing a file name, and, from its shortcut menu (right-click), choosing Open in Protected View.
- A file is opened from an unsafe location   By default, unsafe locations include the user’s Temporary Internet Files folder and the downloaded program files folder. But, you can use Group Policy settings to designate other unsafe locations.

**You can turn off Protected View by following these steps below...**

1. First launch any Office program such as Microsoft Word and then click on File menu present in the ribbon.
2. Now click on Options tab present in the left sidebar.
3. It'll open Options window. Now click on "Trust Center" tab given at the end in left-side pane and then click on "Trust Center Settings" button.
4. Click on "Protected View" tab and in right-side pane
5. All options are enabled by default. Disable the desired option or disable all given options to turn off Protected View completely and click on OK button to save the changes.
6. Close the Office program and now whenever you open a file downloaded from Internet or attached in an email, it'll open normally instead of Protected View.

PS: If the above method doesn't work for you, click on "File Block Settings" tab in Trust Center Settings window and then click on "Restore Defaults" button.

Also you can right click the file itself and go to properties and then click "Unblock". This by default is checked when it's downloaded from the internet...

***If you want to do it in code...***

You can turn this off in code as well, but you haven't provided any code for me to see what you have tried. You can use the `ProtectedViewWindows.Open` function; this doesn't matter if it's protected or not...

```
 ProtectedViewWindows.Open(filename)
```

Comment: Hey Mr CoDeXeR, thanks for that. Please see my edits where I've tried to be clearer on my issue and included my code. Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Did you try what I mentioned in your code... The ProtectedView.. should bypass this screen...

Comment: Yes I did try that, but it seems to open all documents in protected view. I'm actually looking to never open in protected view :)